# Cycle in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

If I open two Java projects in Eclipse which depend on each other, I have to add dependencies between these two projects in the Build Path (Properties -> Java build path). This works fine for one way, but why doesn't allow Eclipse to set the dependencies vice versa? The following error message occurs:

> A cycle was detected in the build path
>   of project 'A'

and

> A cycle was detected in the build path
>   of project 'B'

I know what's causing this error but i wonder why exactly this isn't allowed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That type of circular reference can't be resolved. A needs B to run and B needs A to run. But having cycles between projects like this is a bad thing. **If they both depend on each other, then they probably shouldn't be separate projects since they can't be deployed separately anyway.**

Comment: yes i understand that, but shouldn't this be in the responsible of the programmer?

Comment: yes, but this sort of dependency can't be resolved by eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 13):

Well, if you need to have a cycle you can allow it by changing from error to warning in Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Building->Build path problems -> Circular dependencies.

But I still think that is a bad desing.

Comment: thanks a lot, ill try this. yes its not a optimal solution, but in my android project i don't see a way to avoid this

Answer (score 0):

Changing preference in Eclipse does not help in my case.

The best solution seems to combine two projects into one.